# Is it safe to delete old CoreData xcdatamodel versions?

Tags: core-data-migration

In my project I have too many CoreData model versions (two-digit number). It's a years-long project and stuff has been changed quite a bit through time.

If I'm 100% sure all my users are using the latest model for quite some time now, is there a way I can get rid of old models and 'start fresh' without pulling all the old versions?

I know of solutions where xcdatamodel entries can manually be removed from project file and from the file system, but is it safe? I don't want to end up having "*The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store*" exception.